# How to extract the data from matlab figure and saved it to another vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matlab-figure

I have [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K69tm.jpg) in time series. I want to extract the data which is marked in the figure via black colour and saved it to the different array using matlab. Can any one help me how can extract the datas...??

Comment: What data you want to extract? Look for `callback` properties of axes and figures in help. That way you can read the coordinates of the cursor click and then process it...

Comment: Data already showned in fig. this figure basically plots the datas in time series so I want to get data between this time series(As shown in fig via black mark)

Comment: Do you have the data used to make the figure?

Comment: Yes the data size is 4000 but I want to extract only those data which I marked in circle in fig (I mean data from 500 to 600 range in vertical axis).

Comment: Why do you have to get this from the figure? Why can't you get this from your data array directly?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have plotted the graph from `dataset=[x,y]` then

- Use `'ButtonDownFcn'` and `'CurrentPoint'`properties of your axes to calculate x coordinates of the clicks, say values `click1` and `click2`
- Process your dataset:

```
x1=find(dataset(:,1)>click1);
x2=find(dataset(:,1)>click2);

newdataset=dataset(click1:click2,:);
```

Comment: Isn't the data a time series object?

Comment: I don't see `click1` or `click2` as outputs of `ButtonDownFcn`. What even is a `ButtonDownFcn`!? I can't find `CurrentPoint` either. I'm so confused. HELP ME AAAAAH!

Comment: @rayryeng they might be. I do not know how exactly it was plotted. i supposed that they were plotted from the `dataset` matrix...